# Reversing Linked List with Function

Tags: c, linked-list

I am attempting to reverse and print a linked list by passing the head node to a function. I must then print the reversed list with "printout" funciton. Printout wasn't an issue but the reversal is stumping me. I am only printing the list twice when I attempt to run the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
   int number;
   struct node * next;
} Node;

typedef Node * Nodeptr;

void printout(Nodeptr);

int main()
{
   int n;
   Nodeptr head = NULL;
   if((head = malloc(sizeof(Node))) == NULL)
      return 0;
   head->number = 72;
   head->next = NULL;
   Nodeptr here = head;
   Nodeptr newnode = NULL;
   for(n=0; n<100; n++)
   {
     if((newnode = malloc(sizeof(Node))) == NULL)
        return 0;
     newnode->number = rand()%50 + 50;
     newnode->next = NULL;
     here->next = newnode;
     here = here->next;
     //printf("value of cell %d contains %d\n", n, newnode->number);
    }
    printout(head);
    //sum(head);
   void reverse(head);
   printout(head);
   return 0;
}

void printout(Nodeptr head)
{
 int i;
 for(i=0; i<=100; i++)
  {
    if (head->next != NULL)
     {
       printf("value of cell %d contains %d \n",i, head->number);
       head = head->next;
     }
   }
}

/*void sum(Nodeptr head)
{
  int sum = 0;
  do(sum += Nodeptr head);
    while(head->next != NULL);
   printf("Sum of nodes is %d \n", head->next);
}*/

void reverse(Nodeptr head)
{
  Nodeptr current = head;
  Nodeptr prev = NULL;
  Nodeptr next = NULL;
  int i;
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
      //creating these to hold value while
      //we reassign value to ptr's
      next=current->next;
      current->next=prev;
      prev=current;
      current=next;
    }
   head=prev;

}
```

As I mentioned it's the "reverse" function that is giving me trouble, printout successfully displays a list of 100 cells with random values in the specified range.

```
   void reverse(Nodeptr head)
{
  Nodeptr current = head;
  Nodeptr prev = NULL;
  Nodeptr next = NULL;
  int i;
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
      //creating these to hold value while
      //we reassign value to ptr's
      next=current->next;
      current->next=prev;
      prev=current;
      current=next;
    }
   head=prev;

}
```

I was attempting to create three new nodes to help me juggle the pointers here.
Hopefully this wasn't a poor question, I appreciate any help. Please note that "printout" is commented out and you will need to un-comment if you wish to test this code yourself. I am using codeblocks by the way. Thanks again.

Comment: 0) `void reverse(head);` --> `void reverse(Nodeptr head); reverse(head);`

Comment: 1) `head=prev;` doesn't update caller side variable.

Comment: 2) `if (head->next != NULL)` : Off by one error.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that `reverse` will also have to exchange the pointer to the head of the list. With function `void reverse(Nodeptr head)`, however, you pass the head pointer by value and will thereby not have the chance to alter it in a way that the caller is affected.

I'd suggest to change the signature to

```
Nodeptr reverse(Nodeptr head);
```

and alter the call to

```
head = reverse(head);
```

There may be other issues as well; but this is probably the starting point for further analysis.